# day of the week in Java

Tags: java

PHP has a built-in function that takes a data and returns the day of the week it is (Monday, Tuesday, etc.). Does Java have a similar function?

Comment: Modern solution uses `java.time.LocalDate` and the `DayOfWeek` enum. Ex: `LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( … )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old style(pretty old..)

```
import java.util.*;

public class GetDay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.set(2011, 1, 9); // 1 = Feb  months are zero based remember
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));  
    }
}
```

In java-8 it could be as simple as

```
LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek //get day of week for current day
LocalDate.of(2016, 01, 01).getDayOfWeek //get day of week for a particular day
```

This call return a [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum value which in itself has some nice functions.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Ex: `LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( … )`

Answer (score 4):

Yes [Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK)

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
switch (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
{
   case Calendar.MONDAY: ...;
   case Calendar.TUESDAY: ...;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Calendar class:

Example:

```
Calendar newCal = new GregorianCalendar();
newCal.set(1997, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0);
newCal.setTime(newCal.getTime());    
int day = newCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Reference:

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/determine-the-day-of-the-week.html